# Arduino Uno Wunderground weather station - Ethernet connection failed

Tags: shields, ethernet

I'm new to Arduino. For my first project, I've decided to build a weather station where data is collected via sensors and is then sent to Wunderground. I'm using an arduino uno, an ethernet shield as well as a DHT22 sensor for temperature and humidity.

Everything worked for an hour and then I'm getting "connection Failed" constantly.

I would really appreciate it if you could look into my code. I've tried everything and it doesn't explain the sudden failure of the project. I occasionally get a successful upload after dozens of connection failed messages.

Here's my code. I've removed my weather station password for security reasons.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>
#include "DHT.h"

// Sensor Pins 
#define DHTPIN 7
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
// Variables
float temp;
float hum;

byte mac[] = {
  "de,ad,be,ef,fe,ed"
};
EthernetClient ethernetClient;
unsigned int localPort = 8888;
// Wunderground server details
char SERVER[] = "rtupdate.wunderground.com";
char WEBPAGE[] = "GET /weatherstation/updateweatherstation.php?";
char ID[] = "ICHESTER24";
char PASSWORD[] = "iwqnrlex";

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
unsigned int connections = 1;
unsigned int timeout = 30000;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(38400);
  Wire.begin();
  dht.begin();

  // Connect to internet
  Serial.print(F("\nInitialising Ethernet module"));
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac)){

    Serial.println("Initialisation completed successfully!");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Something went wrong during ethernet module setup!");
  }
} //END OF SETUP

void loop(void) {
  hum = dht.readHumidity();
  temp = dht.readTemperature();
  float tempf = (temp * 9.0)/ 5.0 + 32.0; // Convert Celcius to Fahrenheit
  float dewptf = (dewPoint(tempf, hum));
  Serial.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
  Serial.println("temp = ");
  Serial.println(tempf);
  Serial.println("Humidity = ");
  Serial.println(hum);
  Serial.println("DewPoint = ");
  Serial.println(dewptf);
  // Send all data to WUNDERGROUND
  if (ethernetClient.connect(SERVER, 80)) {
    ethernetClient.print(WEBPAGE);
    ethernetClient.print("ID=");
    ethernetClient.print(ID);
    ethernetClient.print("&PASSWORD=");
    ethernetClient.print(PASSWORD);
    ethernetClient.print("&dateutc=");
    ethernetClient.print("now");
    ethernetClient.print("&tempf=");
    ethernetClient.print(tempf);
    ethernetClient.print("&humidity=");
    ethernetClient.print(hum);
    ethernetClient.print("&dewptf=");
    ethernetClient.print(dewptf);
       ethernetClient.print("&softwaretype=Arduino%20UNO%20version1&action=updateraw&realtime=1&rtfreq=2.5");//Rapid Fire
    ethernetClient.println();
    Serial.println("New data uploaded");
  }else{
    Serial.println("Connection Failed...");
  }
  delay(2500);

}
void resetEthernet() {
 ethernetClient.stop();
 delay(1000);
 Ethernet.begin(mac);
 delay(1000);
 ethernetClient.available();
}
double dewPoint(double tempf, double humidity)
{
  double A0= 373.15/(273.15 + tempf);
  double SUM = -7.90298 * (A0-1);
  SUM += 5.02808 * log10(A0);
  SUM += -1.3816e-7 * (pow(10, (11.344*(1-1/A0)))-1) ;
  SUM += 8.1328e-3 * (pow(10,(-3.49149*(A0-1)))-1) ;
  SUM += log10(1013.246);
  double VP = pow(10, SUM-3) * humidity;
  double T = log(VP/0.61078);   
  return (241.88 * T) / (17.558-T);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume u used a W5100 shield. This shield is capable of having 4 connections open. If the connections are not closed for some reason the chip is unable to make another connection. 
This means after sending u need to close the connection. (else it will work 4 times).

`ethernetClient.stop()`

Just before or after

`Serial.println("New data uploaded");`

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientStop